# code coverage with xcode 4.5 - no gcda generated

Tags: code-coverage, xcode4.5

I have a simple project that run on Xcode 4.5 with Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler.

I have set below flags in build settings:

1. Generate Profiling code: Yes
2. Instrument program flow: Yes Generate
3. Test Coverage files: Yes

I am running the app on iPad 6.0 Simulator and once the app launches I am clicking few buttons and playing around with it.

I am not running unit tests on this, but am manually clicking buttons. Under derived data..., all I am seeing is .gcov files. But No .gcda files are being generated.

Really appreciate any pointers you might have!

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tried the same settings as yours. I was able to generate code coverage files by just running the app on iPad 5.1 simulator. It didn't work for me for iPad 6.0 simulator.

Steps taken by me:

In the main target of the Xcode Project, set the following flags in build settings:

Generate Test Coverage Files : Yes
Instrument Program Flow: Yes

Set these flags only for Debug.

In the info.plist of your application, set 'Application does not run in background' : YES

.gcda files get generated only when the application closes properly. Setting the above flag will close your application when you press HOME button. It will not run in background.
Somehow, this flag did not work for me for iPad 6.0 simulator.

Comment: Thanks Diksha. I was able to get this working using above steps. For running this on simulator I had to press Command + Shift + H to simulate Home buttons and that generated code coverage.

Comment: Is there a fix for this? Xcode 4.6 and still no code coverage files generated for the 6.0 or 6.1 simulators.

Comment: I used Xcode 4.6 and 6.1 simulator, run test (cmd+u), and coverage files are generated no problem.

Comment: After lots of testing I found that having either "-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib" or "-weak-lSystem" in Other Linker Flags  causes no GCDA files with iOS 6.X